# Modeling utility-scale PV in PVLib

Tags: pvlib

I'm trying to model utility-scale PV plants using generation data from NREL's NRSDB dataset, but have not quite figured out how to do so in PVLib. I believe the correct approach should be to create a PVSystem object where I specify modules_per_string and strings_per_inverter (which I have estimated using SAM), then use ModelChain in conjunction with a Location object and weather data from NRSDB.

Using NREL's SAM, using the BP Solar BP3220N module and ABB Ultra 690V inverter, I need 23 modules per string and 9,897 strings in parallel to yield a 50 MW plant. I have tried to reproduce this configuration below.

Below is the code I have been using.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pvlib
from pvlib.pvsystem import PVSystem
from pvlib.location import Location
from pvlib.modelchain import ModelChain
from pvlib.modelchain import basic_chain

def importPSMData():
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\mtcraig\\Documents\\NSRDBData\\dd\\622240_30.77_-99.3_tmy.csv',skiprows=[0,1])
    #Rename paramters for input to PVlib
    df.rename(columns={'DHI':'dhi','DNI':'dni','GHI':'ghi','Temperature':'temp_air',
                        'Wind Speed':'wind_speed'},inplace=True)
    #Rename date parameters in order to run to_datetime
    df.rename(columns={'Year':'year','Month':'month','Day':'day','Hour':'hour',
                        'Minute':'minute'},inplace=True)
    df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']])
    #Set index to DT for run_model call
    df.set_index(df['dt'],inplace=True)
    #Drop unnecessary columns
    df = df.drop('Dew Point', 1)
    df = df.drop('Pressure', 1)
    df = df.drop('year', 1)
    df = df.drop('month', 1)
    df = df.drop('day', 1)
    df = df.drop('hour', 1)
    df = df.drop('minute', 1)
    df = df.drop('dt',1)
    return df

sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('cecinverter')

module = sandia_modules['BP_Solar_BP3220N_Module___2010_'] #18% eff, c-Si
inv = cec_inverters['ABB__ULTRA_1100_TL_OUTD_3_US_690_x_y_z_690V__CEC_2013_']
system = PVSystem(module_parameters=module,inverter_parameters=inv,surface_azimuth=180,
                    modules_per_string=23,strings_per_inverter=9897)

loc = Location(latitude=30.77,longitude=-99.3,tz='Etc/GMT+7',altitude=500)

mc = ModelChain(system,loc,name='test',
            orientation_strategy='south_at_latitude_tilt') 

weatherData = importPSMData()
mc.run_model(times=weatherData.index,weather=weatherData)
print(mc.ac)
```

And here is the output for 1 day, but all output is the same:

```
print(mc.ac)
dt
2013-01-01 00:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 01:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 02:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 03:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 04:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 05:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 06:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 07:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 08:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 10:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 11:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 12:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 13:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 14:00:00    1170000.0
2013-01-01 15:00:00    1170000.0
2013-01-01 16:00:00    1170000.0
2013-01-01 17:00:00    1170000.0
2013-01-01 18:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 19:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 20:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 21:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 22:00:00          NaN
2013-01-01 23:00:00          NaN
```

My weather data for that day is as below:

```
dt       dhi   dni ghi temp_air    wind_speed
1/1/2013 0:00   0   0   0   8.779901123 3
1/1/2013 1:00   0   0   0   8.503381348 3
1/1/2013 2:00   0   0   0   8.082849121 2
1/1/2013 3:00   0   0   0   7.553338623 3
1/1/2013 4:00   0   0   0   6.817102051 3
1/1/2013 5:00   0   0   0   6.063470459 3
1/1/2013 6:00   0   0   0   5.250634766 3
1/1/2013 7:00   0   0   0   4.292138672 3
1/1/2013 8:00   3   0   3   4.388421631 3
1/1/2013 9:00   49  0   49  4.977044678 3
1/1/2013 10:00  177 157 241 6.834771729 3
1/1/2013 11:00  239 131 307 8.402886963 2
1/1/2013 12:00  184 576 518 9.695245361 2
1/1/2013 13:00  90  939 643 10.30196533 2
1/1/2013 14:00  86  926 592 10.1447998  2
1/1/2013 15:00  91  729 420 9.404504395 2
1/1/2013 16:00  123 246 200 8.237115479 2
1/1/2013 17:00  29  0   29  6.443383789 2
1/1/2013 18:00  0   0   0   5.289483643 2
1/1/2013 19:00  0   0   0   4.527764893 2
1/1/2013 20:00  0   0   0   3.753839111 2
1/1/2013 21:00  0   0   0   2.97612915  2
1/1/2013 22:00  0   0   0   2.200036621 2
1/1/2013 23:00  0   0   0   1.460778809 2
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.
-Michael

Answer (score 3):

`PVSystem` + `ModelChain` calculates power for a set of modules, strings, and a *single* inverter. Your model is putting all ~50 MW of your DC power into a single 1.1 MW inverter, so you hit the inverter's max AC for nearly all daylight hours. Depending on your exact plant specifications, you'll need 40-50 of your specified inverters to achieve your rated AC power. Then you probably will want about 9897/45=220 `strings_per_inverter`. Finally, you'll need to multiply your model results by the number of inverters to get total plant power.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I also needed to reshuffle my timezones in order to avoid generation being isolated to only a few hours per day. The solar positioning was not aligning with the weather data I was inputting. Thank you very much for your answer!